# MongoDB updateOne not able to update document when referring an ID as filter

Tags: javascript, mongodb, next.js

I'm trying to update a property value of a single document by sending a request to my NextJs API via fetch.

```
// Update items in state when the pending time in queue has passed, set allowed: true
items.map((item) => {
  const itemDate = new Date(item.added)
  const timeDiff = currentDate.getTime() - itemDate.getTime()
  const dateDiff = timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)

  if (dateDiff >= 7) {
    
    const updateItem = async () => {
      try {
        // Data to update
        const updatedItem = {
          _id: item._id,
          name: item.name,
          price: item.price,
          allowed: true
        }
        console.log(updatedItem)

        await fetch ('/api/impulses', {
          method: 'PATCH',
          body: JSON.stringify(updatedItem)
        })
      } catch (error) {
        alert('Failed to update items status')
      }
    }

    updateItem()
  }
})
```

API receives the data object as a whole and I am able to parse every piece of data I need for updating the MongoDb document from the `req.body`. However, when trying to use the item's `_id` (which is generated by MongoDb and values as `_id: ObjectId('xx1234567890xx')`) to filter the document I need to update, it seems to treat the ID differently.

I've tried to mess around with the format, forcing the object that gets sent to the API to include just the things I want to be updating (and the _id, of course) but still...

```
const jsonData = JSON.parse(req.body)
const { _id } = jsonData

// Fields to update
const { name, price, allowed } = jsonData
const data = {
  name,
  price,
  allowed
}

const filter = {
  _id: _id
}
const update = {
  $set: data
}
const options = {
  upsert: false
}
console.log("_id: ", filter) // returns { _id: 'the-correct-id-of-this-document' }
```

And finally, updating the`db.collection` and returning responses:

```
await db.collection('impulses').updateOne(filter, update, options)

return res.json({
  message: 'Impulse updated successfully',
  success: true
})
```

So, as the `_id` clearly matches the document's id, I cannot figure out why it doesn't get updated? To confirm that this isn't an issue with database user privileges, if I set `upsert: true` in options, this creates a new document with the same _id and the updated data the request included...

Only difference to the other documents created through a submit form is that the id is in the following format: `_id: 'xx1234567890xx'` - so, comparing that to an ID with the ObjectId on front, it doesn't cause a conflict but I really don't get this behavior... After noticing this, I've also tried to include the 'ObjectId' in the ID reference in various ways, but it seemed like initiating a new ObjectId did exactly that - generate a new object ID which no longer referenced the original document.

Any ideas?

Comment: Set `const filter = {
  _id: ObjectId(_id)
}`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I'm not sure how many times I had tried that, and at best it resulted in creating a completely new document with a new ID, when `upsert: true` was set.

This time however, it would seem like this works. It's the type of programming sorcery again... Sure enough the rest of the code has changed since I last tried this and it was just waiting me to try it again.

Big thanks! If you could post it as a formal answer, I can mark this question solved. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You compare an `ObjectId` object from `_id` with a string, this does not work.

Create proper filter object, e.g.

```
const filter = { _id: ObjectId(_id) }
```

or the other way around:

```
const filter = { $expr: {$eq: [{$toString: "$_id"}, _id] } }
```

but this will prevent to use the index on `_id`, so the first solution should be preferred.